# How can I fetch KPIs from a PowerBI report using python?

Tags: python, powerbi

I need to fetch KPIs (revenue change, total cost etc.) from a PBI report.

So far I have tried calling few PowerBI Rest APIs like this-

```
url_groups = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports'
header = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
api_out = requests.get(url=url_groups, headers=header)
```

However, only the report name, type , urls etc. are getting returned in the output, not the KPIs. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI has many API endpoints (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/). You are using the Reports endpoint, that's why you are getting the output you see.

There are other endpoints you might be interested in checking: Dashboard endpoint ([https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/dashboards/{dashboardId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/dashboards/%7BdashboardId%7D)) and Dataset one ([https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7BdatasetId%7D)).

The only thing is that in the documentation looks like there is no specific place where you can get your data from by using the API.
It might be necessary to schedule csv exports from PowerBI and then reading those in Python.

Answer (score 0):

To get at the data in the report you need to send a [DAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-overview) query to the report's Dataset using the [ExecuteQueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/execute-queries-in-group) API.

In Power BI Desktop you can use the [Performance Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-performance-analyzer) to see the DAX query sent by a visual, instead of writing it from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't have access to the dataset. Hence, DAX queries won't work in this case.

Comment: Then there's no supported way to get the data.